# how to access apache solr search in a LAN machine environment?

Tags: php, apache, solr, solrcloud

Iam using solr-5.3.0 version. I installed SOLR in my local machine and succesfully implemeted SOLR search in PHP using CURL.

i used this code to get solr search results..

```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8983/solr/searchCore/select?q=".$encode."&wt=php&indent=true");
```

I need to accesss the solr search from another machine in same LAN network.
in that case, 
I have no idea.

please help. 
thanks....

Comment: Have you tried changing "localhost" to the IP address that SOLR is installed on?

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://<ENTER_SOLR_IP_HERE>:8983/solr/searchCore/select?q=".$encode."&wt=php&indent=true");

Comment: I tried it..yes its working :)